# Unable to connect to cloud server via browser (iptables)

Tags: apache, centos, iptables

I am not sure if stackoverflow allows for server configuration questions as well, but as this might be related to apache I hope someone can help. I am trying to setup my cloudserver to allow for incoming connections on port 80 so that I can see my server files when I enter either http://domain.com in a browser. Apache is installed and I am currently busy setting up my iptables (which I suspect might be the problem).

My current iptables are as follows:

```
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination
 ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere
 ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
 REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-     prohibited

 Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination
 REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-     prohibited

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
 target     prot opt source               destination
```

As this is my first attempt at this (and my network experience goes with what the GUI on MS machines offer) I am not sure if I did it correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work, apache wasn't started :)